# add card object values together

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Im new to programming and Javascript and im a bit stuck on a school assignment atm. My code below works when i log one object like this:
`score([{ suit: 'HEARTS', value: 1 }])`
This logs 11 but if i want to log multiple objects at the same time and add their values together, how could i do that?
For example, if i call these objects below with the values 2, 3 and 4 it should return 9.

```
score([{ suit: 'HEARTS', value: 2 }, { suit: 'HEARTS', value: 3 }, { suit: 'HEARTS', value: 4 }])
```

Here is my code:

```
let score = function (cardObject) {
  let getScore = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < cardObject.length; i++) {
   getScore += cardObject[i].value
   
    if (getScore === 1) {
      return 11;
    } else if (getScore === 2) {
      return 2;
    } else if (getScore === 3) {
      return 3;
    } else if (getScore === 4) {
      return 4;
    } else if (getScore === 5) {
      return 5;
    } else if (getScore === 6) {
      return 6;
    } else if (getScore === 7) {
      return 7;
    } else if (getScore === 8) {
      return 8;
    } else if (getScore === 9) {
      return 9;
    } else {
      return 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your if statements are covering every number, you don't need an if statement for all of them.

**Updated** the function per comments to include if statement to take into consideration face cards.

The first if statement checks for values greater than and equal to 10 and lower than and equal to 13. If so add 10. If card value is 1, add 11. Else add the card's value.

Then I simply return the getStore variable.

Your code was returning the value, which ends the function without calling it again. The return in this case would be the last thing after all of the logic was complete.

```js
let score = function(cardObject) {
  let getScore = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < cardObject.length; i++) {
    let cardValue = cardObject[i].value;
    if (cardValue >= 10 && cardValue <= 13) {
      getScore += 10;
    } else if (cardValue === 1) {
      getScore += 11;
    } else {
      getScore += cardValue;
    }
  }

  return getScore;
}

console.log(score([{
  suit: 'HEARTS',
  value: 10
}, {
  suit: 'HEARTS',
  value: 11
}, {
  suit: 'HEARTS',
  value: 12
}]));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)! I think i explained a bit weird. The values is like playing cards in blackjack, 1-9 should return the same number as the value, value number 10-13(ten, jack, queen, king ) should return 10 and value number 1 (Ace) should return 11. So when i call the function with different object values it should add the values together. If i call the object with the value of 1 (Ace) four times it should return 44. And if i call an object with value of 11(Jack) and 12(Queen) it should return 20. English isn't my native language so i have a hard time to exaplain in text ^^

Comment: @dj92 I updated my answer to take into consideration the face cards.

Comment: Thank you! I will take long look att this to try to understand it fully :)

Comment: @dj92 I added a better description

Comment: Thanks! DO you think its possible to expand the code to make it that ace is either 1 or 11 depending if the score exceeds 21 or not ? Or do i need to rewrite the whole code? I've tried adding this but cant get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function score(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc, {value}) => acc + (value === 1 ? 11 : value), 0);
}
let res = score([{ suit: 'HEARTS', value: 2 }, { suit: 'HEARTS', value: 3 }, { suit: 'HEARTS', value: 4 }]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler approach, that should do the trick:

```js
function score(cardObject) {
  let getScore = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < cardObject.length; i++) {
    switch (cardObject[i].value) {
      case 1: {
        getScore += 11
        break
      }
      default: {
        getScore += cardObject[i].value
        break
      }
    }
  }

  return getScore
}

score([{suit:"HEARTS",value:1}]) // 11
score([{suit:"HEARTS",value:2},{suit:"HEARTS",value:3},{suit:"HEARTS",value:4}]) // 9
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)! I think i explained a bit weird. The values is like playing cards in blackjack, 1-9 should return the same number as the value, value number 10-13(ten, jack, queen, king ) should return 10 and value number 1 (Ace) should return 11. So when i call the function with different object values it should add the values together. If i call the object with the value of 1 (Ace) four times it should return 44. And if i call an object with value of 11(Jack) and 12(Queen) it should return 20. English isn't my native language so i have a hard time to exaplain in text ^^

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do `if num return num` to get the number. But what's actually happening here is the use of the `return` function. Basically, it completely exits the function and gives the value back. So what you would really need to do instead is something like this

```js
let score = function (cardObject) {
  let getScore = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < cardObject.length; i++) {
    //Instead of making it so that we return a bunch of numbers, we check to see if that
    //value from the cardObject array is a 1, and if it is add an 11 to getScore,
    //otherwise, add that number to getScore
    if (cardObject[i].value == 1){
      getScore += 11;
    } else {
      getScore += cardObject[i].value;
    }
  }
  //And then finally we return getScore instead
  return getScore;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)! I think i explained a bit weird. The values is like playing cards in blackjack, 1-9 should return the same number as the value, value number 10-13(ten, jack, queen, king ) should return 10 and value number 1 (Ace) should return 11. So when i call the function with different object values it should add the values together. If i call the object with the value of 1 (Ace) four times it should return 44. And if i call an object with value of 11(Jack) and 12(Queen) it should return 20. English isn't my native language so i have a hard time to exaplain in text

Comment: No worries at all! Easy fix would be to just add that in the `if` statement. Mostly add an `else if (cardObject[i].value >= 10)` and then you would just add 10